# compile ruby 1.9.3 along with required gems to make it as like package bundle

Tags: rubygems, ruby-1.9.3

We don't have ruby 1.9.3 rpm for CentOS 5.x and am looking to compile this ruby version from source. Am able to compile it using below steps,

```
cd /usr/src wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz tar zxf ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz cd ruby-1.9.3-p0 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ruby193 --disable-install-doc --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/lib make && make install
```

And then I will simply zip the ruby193 and distribute to all of my servers. But am looking the way to compile along with required additional gems and so that after I bundle it and when am installing do not need to install any additional gems.

So I can just simply copy the zip file and extract it on all the servers which should work without installing any additional installation requirement. By this way I can maky unique version of ruby on all of my which are running with CentOS 5, CentOS 6 and SunOS. But not sure if this works on CentOS 4 as well , am still using this OS version for few servers due to some application requirements.

**Update:**

Finally am able to make this working with the below way,

- compiled ruby
- installed necessary gems
- make it as tar gz file

Copied to another servers and it works fine. But only issue am facing with libyaml,

```
[root@server-test bin]# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
[root@server-test bin]# gem list
/usr/local/dops/tools/ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:84:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
ffi (1.9.18)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-update (2.6.11)
```

I compiled yaml from source before compile ruby but not sure why am still getting this error when I copy to another servers. But it works fine on the server where I compiled.

Any idea please..

Update 2:

After more debugging found that the library libyaml-0.so.2 doesn't exists.

LoadError: libyaml-0.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I can't compile yaml on all the servers then it will manually again. If I just copy the file `libyaml-0.so.2` from working server to new one under `/lib` and run `ldconfig` will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I compiled from source and created as tar package. I had to compile yaml from source and include the lib folder to make it work.